# Add-in disappears on the latest version of Outlook for Mac once adding Mobile Form Factor

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Add-in disappears on the latest version of Outlook for Mac (16.15 build 180605) once adding Mobile Form Factor to the manifest file:

```
<MobileFormFactor>
    <FunctionFile resid="openButtonUrl" />
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
        <Group id="commandGroupTestID">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="msg1ReadOpen">
                <Label resid="openButtonLabel" />
                <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="scc25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="scc25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="scc25" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="scc32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="scc32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="scc32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="scc48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="scc48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="scc48" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="openButtonUrl" />
                </Action>
            </Control>
        </Group>
    </ExtensionPoint>
</MobileFormFactor>
```

Note - all the resources have been added, and the IDs are set correctly.
The manifest passes the check when installing and sending to Office Store review.

The only difference between the manifest which is working on Outlook for Mac and the one which is not - the MobileFormFactor XML node which was added next to DesktopFormFactor node in xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1" node.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising it. 
Yes, adding MobileFormFactor is causing this issue, we are working on towards fixing it.

Comment: What's the ETA for the fix?

Comment: The fix would be available as part of the July production release, which happens in the 2nd week of July.